# How do I confirm or cancel Notification.requestPermission() prompts?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

### Situation

I'm testing how a web application stack (front and backend) reacts when the user either confirms or denies a request for permission for the application to send notifications (i.e., when javascript on the page calls [`window.Notification.requestPermission()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/requestPermission)).

### Question

How can I instruct a browser being driven by selenium-webdriver to either accept, reject, or maybe even just dismiss the permission request from within the test?

[image: Notification Permission Pop-up in Google Chrome]

---

By the way, I've seen information on how to suppress the "request permission for notification" prompt by changing the browser profile or preferences so that notification permission is always blocked or enabled, but that's not useful since I want to test how the web application behaves before and after the permission was requested and and subsequently accepted or denied.

Answers that provide solutions outside of/in addition to selenium are also welcome if they are:

1. Python based (or can be launched/executed from Python)
2. Work on Linux (X.org/X11 environment)

Since that's the environment I'm using in the Continuous Integration setup that's running the tests.

Comment: have you tried using the Alert function?

Comment: @MoeGhafari, permission confirmations are neither the result of `window.alert()` nor `window.confirm()` so they're invisible to selenium-webdriver APIs dealing with alerts, confirmations, or prompts.

Comment: You could attempt to navigate to the secured page and if it doesn't load within some timeout, assume that it's due to a security prompt? It might not be ideal but it should work.

Comment: @JeffC, there's no way to make "secured" pages that become available once you call `window.Notification.requestPermission()` in javascript, so I don't understand your suggestion...

Comment: I mean to use Selenium to navigate to a page that is secured. If you arrive on the page successfully, you will be able to use Selenium to locate an element known to be on that page. If Selenium cannot locate the element on the page, then you know that it was unsuccessful, e.g. you were prompted for credentials.

Comment: @JeffC, as I mentioned, the request for notification permission in javascript is not protecting access to any page (and cannot be used to do so, even if I wanted). It's just "protecting" the user from receiving [notifications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API). I can, of course, send a notification and [check in javascript if the browser is displaying it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/getNotifications), but that's not what I want to test. I want to test the UI and behavior around the notification permission request.

Comment: The picture helps. I misunderstood the scenario, sorry.